# Is Parallel ATA (PATA) also called Serial Bus?

Tags: hardware, bus

Is Parallel ATA (PATA) also called Serial Bus? If yes, then Serial ATA (SATA) is also called Serial Bus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of them are really serial. Although SATA at least nears it, because it uses only a few data pins.